Conversion of *.wlnb to a widely readable format
I have a WLNB file (see here) that I want to convert to a format that can be accessed by a user who does not have VS Code. For example, it could be converted to an HTML file, a markdown file, or a Jupyter notebook. How can I achieve this?
The option of running Wolfram code through Jupyter notebook is not preferable, as I am encountering some installation issues.
Thank you in advance!

Related post
,
Wolfram Language VScode Extension

By WLNB file, do you mean a notebook?  If the person you want to share a notebook with doesn't have Mathematica installed you could upload the notebook to the cloud and share a link, or print it to a PDF.

@JasonB., I believe the OP is referring to this extension, which allows you to create "Jupyter-like" notebooks, similar to Python notebooks (.ipynb). These notebooks are actually JSON files.

Kostas, if that's the extension you are using, please add a link in your question. Many of us were confused.

@JasonB. I mean a notebook created in VSCode. I forgot to mention it, but I rephrased my question.

@Szabolcs I edited my question.
